# How do I get the String value of the current jsp page I'm in?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to be able to get the String value of the jsp file I'm in so that I can assign it to a temporary String value in Java.

Like so:

```
String pageName = "*myCurrentJSPPage.jsp*"
```

I do not want the entire file path.

Please Help.

Comment: When u create `x.jsp` you can set the variable with `x.jsp`.. and so on?

Comment: As this would be a static value (per jsp), no point trying to figure it out during run time, just hard code it as mentioned by @sanbhat.

Comment: I have multiple jsp files in my project folder. I want to be able to load the proper one when the user selects Which jsp page to load. So the x.jsp file stays the same, I'm just loading a different one. Does that help?

Comment: When you're inside the jsp, you cannot know which jsp you're in. You need to set a request attribute with its name from a servlet.

Comment: @soltirios I guess I'm asking if there is a way I can set that request attribute dynamically

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by [`getServletPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath%28%29) method of `HttpServletRequest`.

```
${pageContext.request.servletPath}
```

[JSTL functions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html) taglib can be used to extract the extension whenever necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<%
String currentjspName = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
System.out.println("*** currentjspName :"+currentjspName);
%>
```

Comment: This is just returning the String of the current class I'm in, not the jsp name. Thanks

Comment: What you are getting in class name and what is your jsp name ?

Comment: @Baadshah: The JSP engine may choose whatever class name it desires for the compiled JSP page.

Comment: class name: ProcessQuery; JSP Name: report_page.jsp